# BLDC motor - how do I find out which phase should be positive and which negative?

Tags: transistors, diodes, dc-motor, brushless-dc-motor

[image]

In this picture the current is either positive, negative or float for the phases. I am confused and can’t figure out which needs to be fed what, for my motor to go the direction I want.

Source: https://www.mdpi.com/2227-9717/9/11/1881

Edit: thanks to -Kartman, I now know about the 6 possibilities and why. Next thing I would like to know the effect of changing the direction of the rotations..

As seen in the image, the motor goes anti clockwise, now if I go clockwise, will the currents be opposite to what they are in the image?

Comment: You’ve got 6 possibilities. Your diagram shows 3 with the rotation being anti clockwise.

Comment: This commutation algorithm is called “six stepping”. You’ll find lots of info out there under that heading.